# in Dot Net Standard 2, some enums have repeating values. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, .net-standard

I am working with dot net standard (2.0) spec and found out
some enums have repeating values,

for example: (this one is also in 4.7.2)

```
enum XPathResultType {
  Number = 0,
  Navigator = 1,
  String = 1,
  Boolean = 2,
  NodeSet = 3,
  Any = 5,
  Error = 6,
}
```

Comment: This is interesting actually, TIL https://dotnetfiddle.net/SgizXG

Comment: Comments in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.SqlXml/System/Xml/Xsl/XsltOld/XsltCompileContext.cs,4e3a9b83a7794741,references) indicate that this is a bug: "Unfortunetely XPathResultType.String == XPathResultType.Navigator (This is wrong but cant be changed in Everett)"

Answer (score 1):

This is a previously known issue identified by Microsoft, as so:

> The overlapping enum values is a known issue. The workaround is to
>   never use the XPathResultType.Navigator value and to always use
>   XPathResultType.NodeSet.

This is discussed is various articles, but the official MS one seems to have been removed from Connect.

This one talks about it: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00daba27-fe32-4b21-a2bc-4cee242b1bd5/xpathresulttypenavigator-and-xpathresulttypestring?forum=xmlandnetfx